# MoveIt can't find custom moveit_controller_manager plugin in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros-humble, pluginlib

For a project using ROS2 as a planning back-end for a robot simulation in Unity I am trying to make a custom MoveIt controller-manager and -handle that send trajectories planned by MoveIt to Unity based on this Project for ROS1: https://github.com/szandara/unity_moveit_manager/tree/master/src/unity_moveit_manager. I am however very much a beginner at using ROS and as such this is my first time making a plugin for MoveIt. While I have searched for official documentation on this, what I could find was either too basic or still for ROS1.

The plugin itself builds without warnings or errors, however when I try to get MoveIt to use this plugin by editing the moveit_controllers.yaml file of a Setup-Assistant generated MoveIt-config like so:

```yaml
# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management

# moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager
moveit_controller_manager: unity_controller/UnityControllerManager

# moveit_simple_controller_manager:
unity_controller:
  controller_names:
    - robot_arm_controller

  robot_arm_controller:
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6
```

And launch MoveIt, for example with demo.launch.py, I will get the following Error messages and a robot that can plan but not execute trajectories:

```
[move_group-3] [FATAL] [1708859046.029615231] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Exception while loading controller manager 'unity_controller/UnityControllerManager': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class unity_controller/UnityControllerManager with base class type moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager does not exist. Declared types are  moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1708859046.029670616] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to reload controllers: `controller_manager_` does not exist.
```

Apparently MoveIt can't find the unity_controller plugin. I've tried a number of ways to fix this issue or just to discover what exactly goes wrong. Among these I have build a demo-plugin following the pluginlib tutorial for Humble (Which worked) and then trying to load my controller-plugin the same way (Which didn't). Here is the Testbench I wrote and the resulting error message:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <pluginlib/class_loader.hpp>
#include <polygon_base/regular_polygon.hpp>
#include <moveit/controller_manager/controller_manager.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;

  pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("polygon_base", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
  pluginlib::ClassLoader<moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager> controller_loader("moveit", "moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager");
  try {
    std::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> triangle = poly_loader.createSharedInstance("polygon_plugins::Triangle");
    std::shared_ptr<moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager> unity_controller_manager = controller_loader.createSharedInstance("moveit_simple_controller_manager::MoveItSimpleControllerManager");
    triangle->initialize(10.0);
    printf("Triangle area: %.2f\n", triangle->area());

    printf("Instance made successfully\n");
  } catch(pluginlib::LibraryLoadException& ex) {
    printf("Library load exception : %s\n", ex.what());
  } catch(pluginlib::ClassLoaderException& ex) {
    printf("Class load exception : %s\n", ex.what());
  } catch(pluginlib::PluginlibException& ex) {
    printf("Some other exception: %s\n", ex.what());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
run plugin_test plugin_tester
Library load exception : According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class moveit_simple_controller_manager::MoveItSimpleControllerManager with base class type moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager does not exist. Declared types are
```

I've noticed that this time the standart moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager doesn't seem to be found either as seen in the different messages. Right now my guess is that for loading MoveIt plugins some extra step is required that I have been unable to discover.

I would be thankful if somebody could point me to the issue that is preventing MoveIt from finding and using my plugin.

In case the issue lies with my plugin itself, here is that:

> Since I have discovered the issue to be with CMakeLists.txt I have shortened this part to the offending file

CMakeLists.txt:

````
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(unity_controller)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(moveit_core REQUIRED)
find_package(trajectory_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(pluginlib REQUIRED)

pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(unity_controller plugins.xml)

add_library(unity_controller src/unity_controller.cpp)
target_compile_features(unity_controller PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17
target_include_directories(unity_controller PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
ament_target_dependencies(
  unity_controller
  "trajectory_msgs"
  "rclcpp"
  "moveit_core"
  "pluginlib"
)

# Causes the visibility macros to use dllexport rather than dllimport,
# which is appropriate when building the dll but not consuming it.
target_compile_definitions(unity_controller PRIVATE "UNITY_CONTROLLER_BUILDING_LIBRARY")

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)
install(
  TARGETS unity_controller
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(
  include
)
ament_export_libraries(
  unity_controller
)
ament_export_targets(
  export_${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the issue to be with Pluginlib and not not MoveIt specific. In CMakeLists.txt the line

```
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(unity_controller plugins.xml)
```

should be replaced with

```
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(moveit_core plugins.xml)
```

as this should contain the package the plugin is for and not the plugin's own.
With this change the plugin is now discovered and used correctly.